# Unity: How to replace placeholder game objects with real artwork?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created temporary primitives while I wait for art and animation to be completed.

I was wondering what the best way of achieving this?

I presume I create a primitive, should I child it in an empty game object? Or create a prefab.?

Does anyone use placeholder animation that would be replaced later?

I tried searching for some recommendations or tutorials but couldn't find any.

Comment: A close ? Was the question too basic for here ?

Comment: I'd think the close is because your problem is more about design that programming. And SO tends to be for programming (though you'll see design question with high appraisal so...so much for consistency).

Comment: @Martin: I think https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is the most appropriate place to ask this question instead of StackOverflow where the questions are more coding-oriented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes just create a prefab. then update it once you have the right asset. please see the link below.

URL:
https://docs.unity3d.com/400/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzjWzUENGzQ